# How do I use throughput controller in Jmeter with multiple samplers

Tags: performance, jmeter, jmeter-plugins, blazemeter

I have a plan that looks like the following:

- thread group

  - throughput controller for homepage (40%)

    - sampler A
  - throughput controller for page 1 (20%)

    - sampler B
  - throughput controller for signup and page view (40%)

    - sampler C (for signup)
    - sampler D (for https(logged in) page view 1)
    - sampler E (for https(logged in) page view 2)

Let's assume that the logged in page view 1 and 2 have to happen right after signup. Due to multiple samplers in the third throughput controller, it's not really possible to achieve the 40% (for that whole group).

For 10 threads, 1 loop, I expect to see the following counts:

- Sampler A: 4
- Sampler B: 2
- Sampler C + D + E: 4

but that's not happening. Any idea how I can achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

This will happen after a certain time of run. 
What are you observing ?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of placing all 3 samplers under one Throughput Controller use 3 Throughput Controllers having samplers C, D and E as children.

Throughput Controllers need to be configured as follows:

- Percent Executions
- Throughput: 40.0
- Per user: unchecked

[image: Throughput Controllers]

See [Running JMeter Samplers with Defined Percentage Probability](https://blazemeter.com/blog/running-jmeter-samplers-defined-percentage-probability) guide for more information on how to control samplers execution rate.

Comment: Unfortunately, this will not help me. Samplers D and E are dependent on C. If C(signup/login) doesn't happen, member page views (D and E) do not make sense.